# Troubles with Regex matching an optional string (powershell)

Tags: regex, powershell

Say I have the following items (line numbers for reference only):

```
1: ER (1000) Attachments
2: ER (1000) Attachments (1)
3: ER (125) Attachments
4: ER (1) Attachments
```

I need to match all of the above. Here's the regex I'm using:

`ER \([0-9]*\) Attachments`

This returns numbers 1,3, and 4. It does not match #2.

`ER \([0-9]*\) Attachments.+`

does not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing I can see wrong with your expression, don't run windows to check powershell...ER \([0-9]+?\) Attachments ???

Comment: What do you mean don't run windows to check powershell?

Comment: Also, there's a chance that the number inside the parenthesis after Attachments could be more than a single digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
ER \([0-9]*\) Attachments.*$
```

This works for me.

**EDIT**

This also works for me:

```
^.*?\(\d+\).*$
```

Comment: This produces the same result. It's not returning the items that have the (###) after Attachments.

Comment: Do you just need to match the line or the individual instances of `\(\d+\)`?

Comment: The entire line `ER (1000) Attachments (1)`

Comment: @Tim: Check my edit. This works for me as well, but so did the first one.

Comment: doh! It works for me too. New to powershell and I forgot to re-hydrate my $spweb object after adding the (1) item.

Comment: It's funny how basic logic goes out the window when working in a new environment ;)